# How to calculate $E(Y_iY_j)$ given moment generating function

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

$M_Y(t) = (e^{t_1}a_1 + e^{t_2}a_2 + \dots + e^{t_\ell}a_\ell)^n$ (multinomial distribution)

I know that

\begin{align}
M_Y'(0) & = E(Y) \\[8pt]
M_Y''(0) & = E(Y^2) \\
& \,\,\, \vdots \\
M_Y^k (0) & = E(Y^k)
\end{align}

But I don't know how to do for two values $$E(Y_iY_j)$$

I think

$$E(Y_i Y_j) = \frac{dM_Y(0)}{dt_it_j}$$

But how would I calculate that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& M_{Y_1,\ldots,Y_\ell} (t_1,\ldots,t_\ell) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(e^{t_1Y_1+\cdots+t_\ell Y_\ell} ). \\[10pt]
& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1 \, \partial t_2} M_{Y_1,\ldots,Y_\ell} (t_1,\ldots,t_\ell) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1 \, \partial t_2} M_{Y_1,\ldots,Y_\ell} (t_1,\ldots,t_\ell) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1 \, \partial t_2} \operatorname E\left( e^{t_1 Y_1 + \cdots + t_\ell Y_\ell} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1 \, \partial t_2} e^{t_1Y_1+\cdots+t_\ell Y_\ell} \right) \\
& \text{(just why this step works} \\
& \phantom{(} \text{could bear examination.)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E \left( Y_1 Y_2 e^{t_1 Y_1 + \cdots + t_\ell Y_\ell} \right). \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore } & \left. \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1\, \partial t_1} \right|_{(t_1,\ldots,t_\ell) \,=\, (0,\ldots,0)} M_{Y_1,\ldots,Y_\ell} (t_1,\ldots,t_\ell) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(Y_1 Y_2).
\end{align}

Comment: To add to this, once you have done this calculation you will get $n(n-1)a_ia_j$.